# Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm a noob on DBA profile. I was installing a **SQL server 2008 R2** on Windows 2008 R2. while installing sql-server i received the following error. I was not able to locate any log at *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap*

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel
>   this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1&EvtType=0xB2652E58%25400xDC80C325
>
> BUTTONS:
>
> &Retry Cancel

Could you please help me troubleshoot/fix this issue?

Comment: You are an local admin?

Comment: You also know that SQL 2008 R2 is end of life,  For IA64 only, SP2 will be supported until 7/9/2019. You probably should use a newer OS and SQL versions.

Comment: @Chuck Yes am a local admin, also this is a test server and dev team are good with 2008 R2

Comment: I am receiving this cryptic message error  with a brand new SQL Server 2017 setup. No idea of how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As it was a new instance, rebuilding the system databases worked for me. Be careful if it is an old instance as all data will be wiped out (you still can take backups and restore data, just a bit more complicated). Details as to how to rebuild the databases [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-2014#Create)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install MSSQL Server 2008 R2 after uninstalling any higher or lower version of MSSQL Server i.e MS SQL Server 2012,2014. Please make sure that you have removed every single file with the name SQL Server except the following three files from the control panel >> Programs >> Uninstall a Program.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 Query Tool ENU
Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU CTP1
```

Also, removed the MSSQL Server folder from the following path

```
C:\Program Files\
C:\Program Files(x86)
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft
```

After then restart the system and try to install it.

Please let me know if you receive any errors.